# Tankless water heater supply configuration

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, tankless

I installed this Stiebel-Electron tankless. It was my first time sweating pipe, I enjoyed the process but I'm unhappy with the pipe alignment, the pipes angle with the heater is not truly plumb.

[image]

I could try again, unsweat the pipes and do a better dry fitting, or I thought about using a flexible connector. Something like this

[image]

but the shortest supply line i can find is 12", which is a little too long:
[image]

How does this look? Should I re-try, and if so, should i look towards using a supply line?

Thanks!

Comment: They make _longer_ hoses. Use one of those and loop it - it'll make a smoother turn anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Does it leak?

If not, move on with life.

Obsessing over plumbing that does not leak is not a good use of your time. Spending money on replacing plumbing that does not leak is not a good use of your money.

Live!

Comment: yep, gotta agree with you ecnerwal. +

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal indeed, it does leak at the top junction, i'll tighten those threads tonight and if it doesn't leak anymore time to move on!

Answer (score 1):

This question is largely opinion based, which we sort of frown upon here.  If it matters to you and it's in a highly visible space, you could re-do the soldered connections.  If it were me, I'd box it in with sheet rock below the valves if I wanted a better appearance.

Comment: thanks @George indeed! I guess I was wondering if having the threads under tension is bad - when dry fitting, I did have to nudge the copper a bit to get into place. But yes i agree, perhaps this is more subjective, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you approached this originally, but I would have proceeded as follows:

1. set the "drops" from the heater vertical,
2. set the elbows for the horizontals,
3. measure and cut the horizontal pipe to fit between the elbows.

That way the result will be at least vertical and neater. However, if the flow rate is relatively high I would have used the swept elbows to reduce the losses and possibly noise. But that does also depend on the rest of the plumbing for those pipes which is not visible. I have re-done some plumbing bits which had SO many fittings that was easily reduced with a bit of planning - of course anytime a boiler is replaced then the spacing etc gets changed.

Comment: awesome, i learned something new with the swept elbows! thank you for taking the time to share

Answer (score 1):

You can re-sweat the pipes if your sense of fastidiousness calls for it.

However you aren't finished with the installation.  The electrical cables need to be moved from "temporary test hookup" to their permanent installation with conduit, or if physical protection is not required here, proper cable clamps to enter those knockouts.

Come to it, the FMC conduit like in your example, alongside the braided steel-jacketed rubber hose, would be a really nice look if done artfully.

Comment: thanks! yes i'm looking into that, it will be nice to exercise a new skill